# $X,Y$ are I.I.D R.V and $P(X+Y\in(0,2))=1$. How to prove $P(X<0)=P(X>1)=0$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I am trying to solve an old exam in my probability course and I stumbled
on a question that I don't have an idea on how to start:

> Let $X,Y$ are I.I.D R.V and denote $U=X+Y$. Assume that
>   $P(U\in(0,2))=1$. Prove that $P(X<0)=P(X>1)=0$

I would appreciate any help on getting started with this question,
I don't even have intuition on why this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the inclusions $\{X<0\}\cap \{Y<0\}\subset \{U<0\}$ and 
$\{X>1\}\cap \{Y>1\}\subset \{U>1\}$. Then use independence and identicalness.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any thought process to get to this ?

Comment: As $X+Y$ lies almost surely between $0$ and $2$ and $X$ and $Y$ have an independent similar behavior, we can guess that $X$ cannot be too large in the negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent you have:
$$P(U<0) \geq P(X<0) P(Y<0)$$
since when both $X$ and $Y$ are negative, so is $U$. Since $P(U<0)$ must be zero by assumption, one of $P(X<0)$ and $P(Y<0)$ must also be zero, and since they are identically distributed, both are.

For the other side you have
$$P(U>2) \geq P(X>1) P(Y>1)$$
and the rest follows analogously.